# change history for kafka connect like liquibase

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a quite large kafka-connect cluster. There are a lot of different sources and sinks.
Now we manage it via UI + have config backups.

How to do it best? Like liquibase/flyway. I want to have changeset history, where I can see what have been changed and by whom. And in case of failure(or in case of deploying to new env) it will be easy to restore everything.

Comment: Would Kafka Control center be a good fit: https://www.confluent.io/product/confluent-platform/data-compatibility.  Tools like liquibase are more for databases and not messaging frameworks.  HTH.

Comment: We use all these. But the question was about changes for kafka connect configuration. Sink and source configs.